# ShadowCopy and MSDeploy on .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, webdeploy

I am trying to solve the issue of my site's dll being locked on deployment. Reviewing this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Nov/07/Avoid-WebDeploy-Locking-Errors-to-IIS-with-Shadow-Copy-for-ASPNET-Core-Apps I wan to use ShadowCopy to help with this problem. I can make this work with .Net 8, where ShadowCopy is a real feature, but in .Net 6 its experimental.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="experimentalEnableShadowCopy" value="true"/>
          <handlerSetting name="shadowCopyDirectory" value="D:\Websites\MyProject\ShadowCopyDirectory\"/>
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And I have set permissions on my ShadowCopyDirectory folder. The IIS AppPool has full control over this folder.

BUT, when I deploy, nothing is created in this ShadowCopyDirectory folder. How can I make ShadowCopy work in .Net 6?